# JSON parsing in ios5 without array name?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, ios5

Here i m putting code of my json file..can anyone help me "How to parse this json file?".I tried a lot of tutorials.I got some hints.But in my json file i dont have array name.so i couldnt use any key value to access those objects.

```
[
{
id: 1,
name: "Ice Cube",
properties: [
{
propertyMeta: {
name: "Color",
type: 5
},
value: "Venfield"
},
{
propertyMeta: {
name: "Size",
type: 1
},
value: "38"
}
]
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Lite Shirt",
properties: [
{
propertyMeta: {
name: "Color",
type: 5
},
value: "Otto"
},
{
propertyMeta: {
name: "Size",
type: 1
},
value: "42"
}
]
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Holiday Tops",
properties: [
{
propertyMeta: {
name: "Color",
type: 5
},
value: "Van Heusen"
},
{
propertyMeta: {
name: "Size",
type: 1
},
value: "39"
}
]
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SBJSON you'd just:

```
NSArray *myArray = [myJSONString JSONvalue];
```

And then loop through it as normal

Comment: I want to put my json into tableview.so i need an array name to get the values of it.this above json file starts with an array itself.but it is not having name for it.how could get it values without name.If i have name"results"like this then i will use                                                                      NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

Comment: Turn the JSON into an array like I posted, then in your cell method, just use: [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: Thank u buddy to spend time for it